# Slide column smoothly in bootstrap4

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, css-animations

I have three `col-md-6` , i only show `box1` and `box2` initially and when user click on `BTN`, i want to show `box2` and `box3`.
BUT  i want to make a smooth transition to the left of all the boxes.
I tried jquery slide but it doesn't work.

How to achieve a smooth transition of boxes to left?

```js
function btnclick() {
  $("#box1").hide("slide", {
    direction: "left"
  }, 1000);
  $("#box3").show("slide", {
    direction: "left"
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 300px;
  border: black;
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</script>
<button onclick="btnclick()">BTN</button>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="box1" class="box col-md-6">Box1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box col-md-6">Box2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box col-md-6" style="display:none;">Box3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function btnclick() {

  $('#box1').animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  }, 2000);
  $('#box3').animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  }, 2000);
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 300px;
  border: black;
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="btnclick()">BTN</button>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="box1" class="box col-md-6">Box1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box col-md-6">Box2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box col-md-6" style="display:none;">Box3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: even with yours suggestion the box2 snaps after the box1 animation finish... i want a smooth transition of box1 and box2 to the left.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
$("#box1").hide("slideLeft");
```

OR

```
$("#box1").hide("slideUp");
```

Comment: no... the box2 snaps after the box1 animation finish... i want a smooth transition of box1 and box2 to the left.